# Installing OpenGL in fedora 14

Tags: drivers, opengl

I am trying to install OpenGL on my Fedora.

But first I am confused with some concepts.

I am using ATI Radeon 5470 card and I downloaded the driver from the official website. Here is the [link](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx)

I want to ask

**Q1:** is this equivalent to OpenGL?

**Q2:** How to uninstall the driver I have installed.

PS:
I used

`sh ati-driver-installer-11-11-x86.x86_64.run`

in the command line. A GUI pops up and after several clicks. The driver is installed, which is quite simple.

**Answer Q2 by myself:**

For the second question:

There is a script installed on my system

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK they provide their own OpenGL implementation with drivers, so you should already have it installed.

You should've had another open source implementation before installing drivers though, likely [Mesa](http://mesa3d.sourceforge.net/).

Tip: I've never had to install OpenGL explicitly in my life.